# Error al instalar Angular CLI en windows 10

Tags: angularjs-2.0, npm

Cuando intento instalar Angular CLI en windows 10 por línea de comandos recibo el siguiente error, la linea de comando es: npm install -g @angular/cli

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 74.122.238.10:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: El error indica que parece un problema de conexión o de configuración del proxy. Por favor, indica qué comando estás ejecutando y la configuración que tengas en npm. Además, incluye las partes relevantes del log para que veamos un mensaje de error más específico.

Comment: Estoy usando este comando por CMD:  npm install -g @angular/cli